# Multiple Protobuf builds for test

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers

I am struggling to set up my Gradle-Protobuf build pipeline. My use case is different from the normal Protobuf use-cases. I need to parse some things, and I use the Protobuf files to test my parser. Simply, I just need to generate the descriptors to test my code.

Further, I need a special build structure, which is not really according to the recommended Google-Setup.

The 'recommended' script:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        proto {
            srcDir 'src/test/resources/descriptors/'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.21.9'
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach {
            task ->
                // If true, will generate a descriptor_set.desc file under
                // $generatedFilesBaseDir/$sourceSet. Default is false.
                // See --descriptor_set_out in protoc documentation about what it is.
                task.generateDescriptorSet = true

                // Allows to override the default for the descriptor set location
                task.descriptorSetOptions.path =
                        "${projectDir}/src/test/resources/compiledDescriptors/${task.sourceSet.name}.dsc"

                // If true, the descriptor set will contain line number information
                // and comments. Default is false.
                task.descriptorSetOptions.includeSourceInfo = true

                // If true, the descriptor set will contain all transitive imports and
                // is therefore self-contained. Default is false.
                task.descriptorSetOptions.includeImports = true
        }
    }
}
```

**What I need:**

I need to test my code on multiple sets of protobuf-files. I can not compile all the files into one .dsc-file. I might get circular dependencies or classes with the same names. Consequently, my idea is to have a subfolder for each case that generates than one .dsc-file - as shown here:

```
resources/
├─ compiledDescriptors/
│  ├─ simpleCases.dsc
│  ├─ otherCases.dsc
├─ descriptors/
│  ├─ moreCases/ 
│  ├─ otherCases/
│  ├─ simpleCases/
```

**Where I struggle:**

I have seriously no idea how to make this work and I tried already multiple options. If I use multiple srcDirs they all end up in one file.